# Why can't I get a value from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I am trying to make a pin cracker, and I don't seem to be able to get the current number from an ArrayList. I am using pin.get(currentChar) to get it. Look at this:

```
package me.pta2002.pincrack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static List<Integer> pinNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Insert your first pin number");
        int num1 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insert your second pin number");
        int num2 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insert your third pin number");
        int num3 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insert your fourth pin number");
        int num4 = scanner.nextInt();
        pinNumbers.add(num1);
        pinNumbers.add(num2);
        pinNumbers.add(num3);
        pinNumbers.add(num4);
        System.out.println("Starting the crack!");

        int currentChar = 0;
        int currentNum = 0;

        String pin = "" + pinNumbers.get(0) + pinNumbers.get(1) + pinNumbers.get(2) + pinNumbers.get(3);
        List<Integer> crackedPin = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        crackedPin.add(0);
        crackedPin.add(0);
        crackedPin.add(0);
        crackedPin.add(0);
        String pinCracked = ""+crackedPin.get(0) + crackedPin.get(1) + crackedPin.get(2) + crackedPin.get(3);

        while(pinCracked!=pin){
            if(currentChar<5){
                currentNum++;
                if(currentNum==pinNumbers.get(currentChar)){
                    crackedPin.remove(currentChar);
                    crackedPin.add(currentChar,currentNum);
                    currentNum=0;
                    currentChar++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(crackedPin);
    }



}
```

Now, I have no clue what the problem is and I would like to get some help. Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at me.pta2002.pincrack.Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

Please help me doing this. (I know I can improve the pin input, I do that later)

Comment: `if(currentChar<5)` you are indexing the list from `0 to 4`, even though it only has 4 elements, meaning the indices go from `0 to 3`

Comment: wow now i feel stupid i completely forgot that it started counting at 0 -.-

Comment: Now I need help: It doesn't seem to be completing the crack. Can anyone help?

Comment: to be fair, for this, I would have rather used an `int[] pinNumbers = new int[4];` then `for(int i = 0; i < pinNumbers.length; i++) { ... }` rather than manually indexing each time (assuming you are not working with java 8 where you can use streams)

Comment: I think it doesn't work because you are adding `crackedPin.add(0);` 4 times, rather than `0 1 2 3`

Comment: i just got it to work :) I don't know what i did but its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code, completely working what you want. Read comments for changes/addition

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static List<Integer> pinNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Insert your first pin number");
        int num1 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insert your second pin number");
        int num2 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insert your third pin number");
        int num3 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insert your fourth pin number");
        int num4 = scanner.nextInt();
        pinNumbers.add(num1);
        pinNumbers.add(num2);
        pinNumbers.add(num3);
        pinNumbers.add(num4);
        System.out.println("Starting the crack!");

        int currentChar = 0;
        int currentNum = 0;

        String pin = "" + pinNumbers.get(0) + pinNumbers.get(1) + pinNumbers.get(2) + pinNumbers.get(3);
        List<Integer> crackedPin = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        crackedPin.add(0);
        crackedPin.add(0);
        crackedPin.add(0);
        crackedPin.add(0);
        String pinCracked = ""; //Changed

        while(!pinCracked.equals(pin)){ //Changed Equating reference before, always true
            if(currentChar<4){ //Changed Out of bound
                currentNum++;
                if(currentNum==pinNumbers.get(currentChar)){
                    crackedPin.remove(currentChar);
                    crackedPin.add(currentChar,currentNum);
                    pinCracked+=currentNum; //Added, Change the string instead
                    currentNum=0;
                    currentChar++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(pinCracked); //Changed
    }



}
```

Comment: Thanks :D I see what I got wrong. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

When `currentChar` is 4, you'll be out of bounds:

```
if(currentNum==pinNumbers.get(currentChar))
```

`pinNumbers` has 4 elements, and since arrays are *zero* based in Java, indexes are in the range [0, N-1].

In your loop, change `currentChar < 5` to `currentChar < 4`.

Note: You're comparing `String`s with `==`, you should use `equals` instead as `==` compares references and not values stored in that reference.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(pinCracked!=pin){
        if(currentChar<5){
            currentNum++;
            if(currentNum==pinNumbers.get(currentChar)){
                crackedPin.remove(currentChar);
                crackedPin.add(currentChar,currentNum);
                currentNum=0;
                currentChar++;
            }
        }
    }
```

You have to change here the if. You need `if(currentChar<4)`
Edit:
in the last run you have currentchar on 4. which is outofbounds

Answer (score 1):

`pinNumbers.get(currentChar)` is out of range when `currentChar == 4`, since you only add 4 elements to the list.

```
    while(!pinCracked.equals(pin)){ // another fix, though not related to the exc
        if(currentChar<pinNumbers.size()){ // this is a safer check
            currentNum++;
            if(currentNum==pinNumbers.get(currentChar)){
                crackedPin.remove(currentChar);
                crackedPin.add(currentChar,currentNum);
                currentNum=0;
                currentChar++;
            }
        }
    }
```